# How to retrieve elements from xml soap response

Tags: xml, xpath

Below is my xml file format(soap response) and i want retrieve each property and show in jsp?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.7.0" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="com.vcompack.XRSTService.MashProfile">



        <void property="build">
       <string>5-6-8</string>
      </void>
      <void property="careof">
       <string> Mariya</string>
      </void>
      <void property="dist">
       <string>7</string>
      </void>
      <void property="name">
       <string>GUNTUR</string>
      </void>
      <void property="dob">
       <string>01/01/1976</string>
      </void>
      <void property="vid">
       <string>1001100</string>
      </void>
      <void property="gender">
       <string>F</string>
      </void>
      <void property="mandal">
       <string>32</string>
      </void>
      <void property="m_name">
       <string>TENALI</string>
      </void>
      <void property="name">
       <string>Ponjamma</string>
      </void>
      <void property="phoneNo">
       <string>101</string>
      </void>
      <void property="pincode">
       <string>522201</string>
      </void>
      <void property="swstxn">
       <string>WS-TXN:20150622092733878</string>
      </void>
      <void property="scode">
       <string>1</string>
      </void>
      <void property="status">
       <string>100</string>
      </void>
      <void property="street">
       <string>Vari Street</string>
      </void>
      <void property="uid">
       <string>6524588</string>
      </void>
      <void property="village">
       <string>12</string>
      </void>
      <void property="village_name">
       <string>Tena</string>
      </void>
     </object>
    </java>
```

I tried all sorts by placing lot of jars in lib but nothing provided solution.Lot of ppl suggested to use xpath.Could anybody help me retrieving all properties in JAVA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the below path expression returns all attributes named `property`

```
//@property
```

In java, you can use the following code:

```
     XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String expression1 = "//@property";
        String expression2 = "//void/string";
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("soapMessage.xml");
        NodeList nodes1 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression1, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes2 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression2, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes1.getLength(); i++) {
            Attr attr = (Attr) nodes1.item(i);
            Element element = (Element) nodes2.item(i);
            String output = attr.getNodeValue()+'-'+element.getTextContent();
            System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: Thx dude....but it is only printing property names....how to retrieve their corresponding values(values in string tags above)

Comment: what is the output you want to get? something like: build, careof, dist, etc.

Comment: i want output as 
build-5-6-8      careof-Mariya         name-guntur       m_name-tenali             dob- 01/01/1976                     uid  -6524588